Can you invoke a number of SYCL kernels based on an integer stored in device memory?
Does SYCL have an analogous feature to Direct3D's, or Unity's ComputeShader.DispatchIndirect, where you can launch x number of kernels where x is an integer stored on GPU memory. This avoids having to read back an integer value from GPU memory.
All of the kernel invocation functions documented in SYCL-2020 spec section 4.9.4.2. (SYCL functions for invoking kernels) only mention invoking kernels with a host-side number of invocations.

What is the use case? I am not sure I follow why you would want to do this. The host device is what instructs the launch of the kernels, the device would not have the control to launch kernels, part of the reason for this is that a host might be connected to many GPUs and so the queue will distribute the work across them all potentially.

The use case is when one kernel produces a variable amount of work for a second kernel to complete. In rendering, let's say there is a buffer of 1000 asteroids, and the first kernel partitions the asteroids into an initial segment of ones that are visible and the rest which are not visible, recording in GPU memory the count. The second kernel which then renders the asteroids needs to only be launched with enough threads to cover the visible ones. Presumably it is faster to only launch 1 thread instead of the full 1000 threads, where 999 of them do read data but decide to do nothing else.

So basically similar use-cases as CUDA Dynamic Parallelism.

SYCL doesn't have anything like CUDA's Dynamic Parallelism right now. You can propose this, it's possible there are already discussions about it. The issue tracker is probably a good place for that https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SYCL-Docs/issues

Okay, in Direct3D 12 this is known as ' work graphs'

I don't know about Direct3D graphs, but at least in CUDA, graphs are used for a somewhat different use case (there are SYCL extensions being worked on for this use case; look up SYCL graphs). CUDA dynamic parallelism typically has a fairly narrow use case and often does not perform as well too. My recommendation would be to verify your assessment that launching a smaller kernel will be much  faster than a kernel for the full problem size with early exit. Early exit would allow the unneeded work groups to immediately free up resources for other groups.
